# HTML разметка и код PHP

Tags: php, html, include

Когда подгружаю файлы includ'ом, то HTML код шаблона в исходном коде страницы разбросан по частям как-то, хотя изначально код был размечен правильно, красиво.

Если когда-то сталкивались с таким, то подскажите, как быть. Не хотелось бы ужасный исходный код просто.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Просто не надо в файлах php, которые вы подключаете через include, использовать html разметку. Например:

```
-----------------------------------file.php----------------------------------
здесь ваш код php, здесь не должно быть html разметки

-----------------------------------index.php---------------------------------
<?php
include('file.php');
здесь ваш код и в этом же файле может быть html разметка.
?>
```